# Error when trying to use session-management

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to place `session-management` in my `security-application.xml` file.

Error:

`Invalid content was found starting with element 'session-management'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":intercept-url,`

[image]

I tried to put in other places but without success.

Advice?

------------------------UPDATE ONE------------------------

I tried:

```
<security:session-management invalid-session-url="/logonTimeOut.jsp">
            <security:concurrency-control expired-url="/logonTimeOut.jsp"/>
        </security:session-management>
```

and it is still not working.

Comment: Looks like an XML schema validation error to me. Can you please add the whole XML and the whole error message to your question? Especially the namespace declarations would be important. E.g. the line with `xmlns:security=...`

Answer (score 1):

I think your xml configuration is not correct .Change xml configuration like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd"
>

    <http create-session="always" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/anonymous*" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

        <csrf disabled="true"/>

        <form-login login-page='/login.html' authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler" authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=true"/>

        <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
        <remember-me key="uniqueAndSecret" token-validity-seconds="86400"/>

        <session-management invalid-session-url="/invalidSession.html">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="2" expired-url="/sessionExpired.html"/>
        </session-management>

    </http>

    <beans:bean id="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.baeldung.security.MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user1" password="user1Pass" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
                <user name="admin1" password="admin1Pass" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: That did not work so I tried ` 
     
`<security:session-management invalid-session-url="/logonTimeOut.jsp"> <security:concurrency-control expired-url="/logonTimeOut.jsp"/> </security:session-management>` and still doesn't go to that page.

Comment: I also need CSRF enabled

Comment: remove this <csrf disabled="true"/>